# SFDC Import Lead via API - how to import notes

Tags: api, salesforce

I am using the SFDC API to import leads into SFDC.  I want to set the Lead Notes field within the import.  What is the database field name for the Lead Notes field?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Notes are stored in the [NoteAndAttachment standard object](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_noteandattachment.htm#topic-title) . 
The ParentId field in NoteAndAttachment points to the Lead Id field when a note is added.